# How to convert an Object to array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following object I created from a json file using jquery $.get.
console.log(array);

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0
    :
    Object
    country
    :
    "Cameroon"
    employ_count
    :
    50
    __proto__
    :
    Object
    1
    :
    bject
    7
    :
    Object
    length:8
    __proto__
    :
    Array[0]
```

I am trying to convert each object to an array of this type ['Cameroon', 58], ['Germany', 58]....

I tried using jquery $.makeArray

```
var array = $.makeArray(emObj);
```

but this still returns an object.

Comment: @nnnnnn typing error. I corrected that!

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the original JSON? (Is it like `[{"country":"Cameroon", "employ_count":50}, {"country":"Germany", "employ_count":58}]`?) That console logged version is a bit hard to read.

Comment: yes , that's what the original looks like {
  `"countries": 
  [
 {
  "country": "Cameroon",
  "employ_count": 50
 } , ...] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your input is an array of objects, and your desired output is an array of arrays. This is easy with jQuery's [`$.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), but the only reason to use jQuery for this is if you're supporting IE < 9, because all modern browsers support the native [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var input = {
  "countries": [
    { "country": "Australia", "employ_count": 22 },
    { "country": "Cameroon", "employ_count": 50 },
    { "country": "Germany", "employ_count": 13 }
  ]
};

var output = input.countries.map(function(v) { 
  return [v.country, v.employ_count];
});

var outputWithjQuery = $.map(input.countries, function(v) { 
  return [[v.country, v.employ_count]];
});

console.log(output);
console.log(outputWithjQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the double `[[ ... ]]` in the jQuery version is not a typo: if you return an array from the `$.map()` function jQuery will flatten it, and returning an array of one element that is the actual array you want fixes that. (The native `.map()` method doesn't have this "feature".)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without using any library dependency like *jquery*.

```
res.push([elem['country'], Number(elem['employ_count'])]);
```

```js
var arr = [{
  country: "Cameroon",
  employ_count: "58"
}, {
  country: "Germany ",
  employ_count: "50"
}];

function calc(arr) {
  var i,
    len,
    res = [];
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    elem = arr[i];
    res.push([elem['country'], Number(elem['employ_count'])]);
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(calc(arr));
```

Comment: @Obasi Is this what you were looking for? Let me know if you need some changes.

Comment: Note: the numbers in the OP's input actually are numbers, so no need to call `Number()`.

Comment: In the rest of the program if I concatenate another string say 
"50" + "28"
If not Numbered, it will be "5028". Just wanted to make sure that dont happen.
Optional again. :D

Comment: But...making the value a number doesn't mean it won't be coerced back to a string if you concatenate it together with a string. `Number("50") + "28"` is `"5028"`. In any case, as I said before the OP's values are already numbers, *not* strings.